# undefined reference to 'sqrt' but only when using variables AND only in CodeBlocks

Tags: c, compiler-errors

I am using Code::Blocks 20.03 on Linux. When I try to compile the following code using the Build (F9) function I get `undefined reference to 'sqrt'`:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main() {
    int a = 5;
    float b = sqrt(a);
    printf("%f", b);
}
```

When I put 5 in place of the `a` in sqrt, the code compiles and runs. When I copy this code to an online compiler, it runs. When I manually `gcc code.c -o code -lm`, the code runs.

I'm tempted to believe that the problem is with CodeBlocks, however, I also realise that I'm a newbie to programming and might not have set everything up right. What else could I try to be able to make conclusions here and hopefully to find a solution?

Comment: My guess is that CodeBlocks does not add `-O2` and that when `5` constant is used GCC calculates sqrt at compile time (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_folding) but when a variable is used it cannot optimize it and needs `-lm`.

Comment: Try going Project -> Build Options -> Linker Tab and add '-lm' (without the quotes) to Other Linker Options

Comment: @kaylum, those instructions did help, adding  'm' as the library name. I guess for my problem it is more suitable to change the Linker settings in Settings > Compiler rather than for each project as math.h is a quiet often used library so I don't have to do it every time. Thanks for the help!